# Does zero constitute an element in the construction of a non-empty set in Number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If my set has '0', is this 'null' or an element in the study of Number theory?

Comment: The set $\{0\}$ has precisely one element. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does. So zero is taken to be an element. Is this a universal standard or are there certain areas in mathematics where '0' is taken to be 'null'?

Comment: I hesitate to answer your question because I don't want to cause any confusion, there *are* certain situations where $0$ is best ignored when counting the number of elements; in particular, it is sometimes best to ignore $0$ if we're dealing with the multicategory of sets with $0$ and $0$-preserving functions. So if we're viewing $\{0\}$ as a set-with-$0$, then arguably its cardinality is best taken as $0$. **However** most people will not have a damn clue what you mean if you start talking like this. Almost **all** mathematicians hold that $\{0\}$ has precisely one element.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have 1 element ${0}$ in your set, the set has 1 element. And to answer your question in the comment, if we stay in set theory $S= {0} \implies S$ is not $\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes, A set that contains zero is not empty

Answer (score 0):

well it all depends on the operation. For example when we add a number $x$ to $0$

$x + 0 = x $ for any value of $x$

Now in set theory , the empty set $\emptyset$ behaves the same like $0$ under the union operation we say that $ A \cup \emptyset = A$ for any set $A$